# Logical error executing wrong if statement block

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My program pulls data from 2 tabs of the same spreadsheet; However, it keeps executing from the wrong 'if' statement block. e.g `var region = ss.getRange(i,5);` contains[us, ca, de, br, mx] and `var user1 =bs.getRange(i,1);` contains[us, ca, de]. I want my if statements to compare if user 1 contains any values of region then to execute and if it doesn't to execute the second 'if' statement so it can send it to user2CC. In this example it looks like my program keeps going based of of the 'decision' rather than whether or not regions are == or != to user1.
Also I apologize for any formatting issues I may have here, I'm very new and learning the ropes.
I appreciate you taking the time to read and look into this.

I also noticed that if I include another if statement including `decision == "wrong"` and `user1 == region` but not include an additional one like `user1 != region && decision == "wrong"` it executes fine?

```
function sendEmails() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main").activate();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  var bs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Regions").activate();
  var lRow = bs.getLastRow();


  // Fetches templates for email
  var Acceptable = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  var Wrong = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(2, 1).getValue();


  var user1CC = "main@email.com" + ',' + "user1@email.com";
  var user2CC = "main@email.com" + ',' + "user2@email.com";


  // loops through "Main" spreadsheet to check if email has been sent and pull necessary data to construct email
  for (var i = 2; i <= lr; i++) {

    var cBox = ss.getRange(i, 13).getValue();
    var region = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    var type = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
    var decision = ss.getRange(i, 15).getValue();

    // loops through "Regions" tab in spreadsheet to get specific regions by person(column)
    for (var j = 2; j <= lRow; j++) {
      var user1 = bs.getRange(j, 1).getValues();

      if (cBox == false) {

        if ((user1.includes(region[j]) && (decision == "Acceptable") {
          var check = ss.getRange(i, 13).setValue("Yes");
          var time = ss.getRange(i, 14).setValue(new Date());
          var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();   
          var decision = ss.getRange(i, 15).getValue();
          
          var messageBody = Acceptable.replace("{Decision}", decision);
          Logger.log(messageBody);
          var subjectLine = "subject";

          MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody, {
            cc: user1CC
          });
          break;

        }


        if ((user1.indexOf(region[j] == -1) && (decision == "Acceptable") {

            var check = ss.getRange(i, 13).setValue("Yes");
            var time = ss.getRange(i, 14).setValue(new Date());

            var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
            var decision = ss.getRange(i, 15).getValue();
            var messageBody = Acceptable.replace("{Decision}", 
             decision);
            var subjectLine = "subject";
            MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody, {
              cc: user2CC
            });
            Logger.log(messageBody);
            break;
          }

        } //ends cBox statement
      } // ends 'for' loops that iterates cBox and 'if' statements
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try using indexOf() or includes for the region.  Look it up yourself in your favorite javascript reference.   Currently your asking for equality and  looks like you want to ask if it contains or includes something.

Comment: I've made changes to include() for both statements and still keep getting the same output?

Comment: I would advice you two things: 1) simplify your code as much as possible 2) try to see what each variable contains and make sure they contain what you expect them to contain. It is difficult for us to find an issue on something we have no idea why it is developed like that, we don't have a picture of your sheet, and we don't know what each variable contains.

Comment: update you code

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information? In any case, I think the problem is you have a string and you're treating it as an array, but more information would be needed in order to make sure that's the case.

Comment: I cannot understand your purpose. If you don't make that clearer, and focus your question on a single specific issue (I think would code would need a substantial reworking), your question is likely to get closed.

Comment: Was able to figure it out! Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate your code on my end and the problem lies with the condition you placed in your if-statements. In the code snippet below:

```
if((user1 == region)  && (decision == "Acceptable") && (type == "Video"))
```

You are trying to compare **user1** which is an array of values *["us", "ca", "de"]* to **region** which is another array of values *["us", "ca", "de", "br", "mx"]*. You cannot simply put and compare these two arrays using **user1 == region** because that statement will always return *False* due to their different values as an array.

If you are going to compare values between arrays, they should be accessed per item by using their index (ex. region[j]). Also, you can try and use the include() function of javascript which checks whether an array contains a specific value in it. You can try it by rewriting the if-statements like this:

```
if((user1.includes(region[j]))  && (decision == "Acceptable") && (type == "Video"))
```

As for the 2nd if-statement, you can replace the **if** by **else if** to prevent the code from running that statement if the first condition is satisfied. Also, you can use the javascript function *indexOf()* to assess if the **region** value does not exist in **user1**. The *indexOf()* functions returns -1 if the value passed does not exist in the array being assessed. Please see sample code below:

```
if((user1.indexOf(region[j]) == -1) && (decision == "Acceptable"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I changed those values on my end but I still keep getting the same output? is it possible it might be something where some of my variables  or for loops are placed?

Comment: It is possible. It is also possible that this is because your loop starts with value of 2 in j which means assigning j as the index for region will make the checks start at the 3rd item in the region array. You can try using region[j-2] to start your checks with the first item in region.

Comment: Let me know if this solves your problem @hotsriracha :)

Comment: I unfortunately didn't make it very clear so it didn't work. Had to change user1.incudes(region[j]) to user1.some(arr => arr.includes(region)); and just leave the else if with a decision!